# How to encode an .ics header from JavaScript to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, encode, icalendar

How can I post a JavaScript variable like the one below into a PHP script? (This is part of a .ics header):

```
var contents = "" +
'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' +
'\n' +
'VERSION:2.0' + 
'\n' + 
'PRODID:-// LIVEMEETING INTG//EN' +
'\n' +
'METHOD:CANCEL' +
'\n' +
'BEGIN:VEVENT' +
'\n' +
'UID:' + liveMeetingId + '@email.com' +
'\n';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple string. You can use AJAX to send it to a server-side script; the easiest way is via jQuery's [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I am not going to be able to utilize jQuery for this project but I could at least use it for test purposes.